# How to detect frequencies with matplotlib spectrogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, spectrogram

I have the following spectrogram of a pressure signal:

[image]

The data is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwhEMUIYGyTczFWSk1RX1BTYVU/view?usp=sharing).

I am trying to calculate frequency of the different harmonics of the pressure fluctuation. I made an attempt in calculating some of them shown by the white horizontal dotted lines in the figure. But all frequencies
picked up by the code are in between. I need to detect the frequency of all the harmonics accurately. The code I used for detection:

```
from __future__ import division
from matplotlib import ticker as mtick
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from bisect import bisect
from scipy import interpolate
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import heapq
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = np.genfromtxt('spectrogram.dat', skiprows = 2, delimiter = ',')
pressure = data[:, 1] * 0.065
time = data[:, 0]
time_start_ignition = 40


with PdfPages('Spectorgram.pdf') as spectorgram_pressure:
    _spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency_ = plt.figure(figsize=(5.15, 5.15))
    _spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency_.clf()
    spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency = plt.subplot(111)
    cax = plt.specgram(pressure * 100000, NFFT = 256, Fs = 50000, noverlap=4, cmap=plt.cm.gist_heat, zorder = 1)
    spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.grid(False, which="major")
    spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.set_xlabel('Time (s)', labelpad=6)
    spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.set_ylabel('Frequency (Hz)', labelpad=6)
    spectrum, freqs, t, im = cax
    dB = 10*np.log10(spectrum)
    f = interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(t, freqs,  dB.T) # but this uses xy not ij, hence the .T
    xnew = np.linspace(t[0], t[-1], 100*len(t))
    ynew = np.linspace(freqs[0], freqs[-1], 10*len(freqs)) # was it wider spaced than freqs on purpose?
    znew = f(xnew, ynew).T
    k = len(ynew) / 8
    smt = sm.nonparametric.lowess(znew[:, bisect(xnew, (time_start_ignition * max(xnew))/(max(time)))], np.linspace(0, len(ynew), len(ynew)), frac = 0.2)[:,1]
    i_change = []
    dsmt2 = np.diff(np.diff(smt))
    print dsmt2[10]
    for i in range(len(smt) - 3):
        if 0 >= dsmt2[i] and  dsmt2[i + 1] >= 0:
            i_change = np.append(i_change, i)
    i_change = np.int_(i_change)
    frequency_first_harmonic = ynew[np.argwhere(znew == np.nanmax(znew[i_change[0]:i_change[1], bisect(xnew, (time_start_ignition * max(xnew))/(max(time)))]))[0][0]]
    frequency_second_harmonic = ynew[np.argwhere(znew == np.nanmax(znew[i_change[1]:i_change[2], bisect(xnew, (time_start_ignition * max(xnew))/(max(time)))]))[0][0]]
    frequency_third_harmonic = ynew[np.argwhere(znew == np.nanmax(znew[i_change[2]:i_change[3], bisect(xnew, (time_start_ignition * max(xnew))/(max(time)))]))[0][0]]
    frequency_fourth_harmonic = ynew[np.argwhere(znew == np.nanmax(znew[i_change[3]:i_change[4], bisect(xnew, (time_start_ignition * max(xnew))/(max(time)))]))[0][0]]
    frequency_fifth_harmonic = ynew[np.argwhere(znew == np.nanmax(znew[i_change[4]:i_change[5], bisect(xnew, (time_start_ignition * max(xnew))/(max(time)))]))[0][0]]
    frequency_sixth_harmonic = ynew[np.argwhere(znew == np.nanmax(znew[i_change[5]:i_change[6], bisect(xnew, (time_start_ignition * max(xnew))/(max(time)))]))[0][0]]

    spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.axhline(frequency_first_harmonic, color = 'white', linewidth = 0.75, linestyle = ':')
    spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.axhline(frequency_second_harmonic, color = 'white', linewidth = 0.75, linestyle = ':')
    spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.axhline(frequency_third_harmonic, color = 'white', linewidth = 0.75, linestyle = ':')
    # spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.axhline(frequency_fourth_harmonic, color = 'white', linewidth = 0.75, linestyle = ':')
    # spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.axhline(frequency_fifth_harmonic, color = 'white', linewidth = 0.75, linestyle = ':')
    # spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.axhline(frequency_sixth_harmonic, color = 'white', linewidth = 0.75, linestyle = ':')   
    spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.axvline((time_start_ignition * max(cax[2]))/(max(time)), color = 'white', linewidth = 0.75, linestyle = ':')
    y_min, y_max = spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.get_ylim()
    cbar = plt.colorbar(orientation='vertical', ax = spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency, fraction = 0.046, pad = 0.2)
    cbar.set_label('Power spectral density (dB)', rotation=90)
    primary_ticks = len(spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.yaxis.get_major_ticks())
    pressure_vs_time = spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.twinx()
    pressure_vs_time.grid(False)
    pressure_vs_time.plot((time * max(cax[2]))/(max(time)), pressure, linewidth = 0.75, linestyle = '-', color = 'k', alpha = 0.7, zorder = 3)
    pressure_vs_time.set_ylabel('Cylinder pressure (bar)', labelpad=6)
    pressure_vs_time.yaxis.set_major_locator(mtick.LinearLocator(primary_ticks))
    spectorgram_pressure_vs_frequency.set_xlim([0, max(cax[2])])
    spectorgram_pressure.savefig(bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: It's quite difficult to follow your code, can you please give an overview of how are you calculating the harmonics. Also commenting and separating your code in sections would help, 'data retrieval', 'data analysis', 'plotting' and so and so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is closer to what you need

[image]

I really couldn't understand how you were calculating the harmonics, so I just tried to find the peaks of the spectrum values at the last time, when the signal is already stable

```
sample=np.transpose(np.array(spectrum)[:,10])

ind=[]

wind=10

for i in xrange(7):
    maxind=np.argmax(sample) #find the index of the max value
    ind.append(maxind)       #save that index
    sample[max(0,maxind-(wind/2)):maxind+(wind/2)]=0    #clean around one window size chunk of data to suppress that peak

x=freqs[ind]


frequency_first_harmonic = x[1]  #drop x[0] because its going to be 0
frequency_second_harmonic = x[2]
frequency_third_harmonic = x[3]
frequency_fourth_harmonic = x[4]
frequency_fifth_harmonic = x[5]
frequency_sixth_harmonic = x[6]
```